# Value of $a+a^a+a^{a^a}+a^{a^{a^a}}+... $

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form

Is there any closed form expression of $a+a^a+a^{a^a}+a^{a^{a^a}}+...$ up to $n$ terms? I am mostly interested in $a=2$

My try:

$a+a^a+a^{a^a}+a^{a^{a^a}}+... =a(1+a^{a-1}+a^{{a^a}-1}+a^{{a^{a^a}}-1}+... )$, but I do not know how to continue.

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form. There is not really a closed form for $a,a^a,a^{a^a},\dots$ without adding a new function.

Comment: If $n$ is sufficiently big i.e bigger than $5$ the series is approximately the last term.

Answer (score 6):

With $a=2$, the first terms make the sequence
$$\{2,6,22,65558,\cdots\}$$ The problem is that the next one is
$$\sim 2.0035\times 10^{19728}$$

Notice that, just by itself,
$$2^{65558} \sim 8.4034\times 10^{19724}$$